# Barcode generation using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, barcode

I have created barcode generation code using php codeigniter. It generates barcode but after scanning that barcode result shows **no barcode data found** on selected page. Please look into below code

```
try{
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    $this->load->helper('barcode');

    $lineitem_id = $this->uri->segment(4);

    $d_data = $this->MainModel->getColumnById1('tblproduct_packing_lineitems','*','packing_box_count',$lineitem_id);
    for($i=0; $i<count($d_data);$i++){
        $dl_data = $this->MainModel->getColumnById1('tblproduct_packing','*','id',$d_data[$i]->packing_id);
        $item_data = $this->MainModel->getColumnById1('tblitems','*','id',$d_data[$i]->product);
    }

    for($j=0;$j<count($dl_data);$j++){
        $data['packing_no'] = $dl_data[$j]->packing_id;
        $data['packing_date'] = $dl_data[$j]->packing_date;
    }
    for($k=0;$k<count($item_data);$k++){
        $data['description'] = $item_data[$k]->description;
        $data['long_description'] = $item_data[$k]->long_description;
    }

    $this->load->library('barcode_lib');
    for($i=0;$i<count($d_data);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<count($dl_data);$j++){
            for($k=0;$k<count($item_data);$k++){
                $hash1 = 
                // $d_data[$i]->batch_id.' '.$d_data[$i]->heat_id
                $item_data[$k]->description.' '.$item_data[$k]->long_description
                .' '.substr($dl_data[$j]->packing_id.'_'.$d_data[$j]->id,5);    
            }
        }
    }
    $barcode_data = array("barcode"=>$hash1,
                          "barcode_status"=>"generated"
                            );

    foreach($d_data as $update_row){
        $res = $this->MainModel->updateById('tblproduct_packing_lineitems','id',$update_row->id,$barcode_data);
        $hash = $hash1;
    }

    $hash = $hash1;

    //$config['company'] = "testcompany";
    $config['barcode_content'] = $hash;
    $config['barcode_type'] = "Code128";
    $config['barcode_font'] = 0;
    $config['barcode_font_size'] = "10";
    $config['barcode_height'] = '1000';
    $config['barcode_width'] = '20000';
    $config['barcode_num_in_row'] = "2";
    $config['barcode_page_width'] = "100";
    $config['barcode_page_cellspacing'] = "100";
    $config['barcode_generate_if_empty'] = 0;
    $config['barcode_formats'] = null;

    $data['barcode_config'] = $config;
    $data['barcode_content'] = $hash;

    // get the newly generated barcode
    $barcode_instance = Barcode_lib::barcode_instance($result, $config);
    //if($res){
    $html=$this->load->view('admin/production/packing/packing_barcode', $data, true);

    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output();
}catch (Exception $e) {
    set_alert('error', $e->getMessage());
    redirect(admin_url('PackingController'));
}
```

Comment: what troubleshooting steps have you taken?

Comment: where are you using $barcode_instance?

Comment: @Alex I dont have much idea about barcode generation,please help me out in this.

Comment: @mokNathal yes i have used barcode_instance

Comment: @rohit you have to help yourself first, we don't have your system so we can't take the necessary troubleshooting steps. you must go through and assure what you are expecting to happen is happening. add echos, print_rs, check the queries are executing .etc.

Comment: @Alex I have checked with print_r, it shows proper data but after scanning barcode it doesn't fetch any data